# global variables across files and numpy behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, global-variables

I have three files: `bar.py`, `foo.py`, and `main.py`.

```python
# bar.py
import numpy as np
global y
x=0
y=0
z=np.array([0])
```

```python
# foo.py
from bar import *
def foo():
    x=1
    y=1
    z[0]=1
```

```python
# main.py
from foo import *
from bar import *
print(x,y,z)
# 0 0 [0]
foo()
print(x,y,z)
# 0 0 [1]
```

Question: *Why did `x` and `y` not change their values while `z` did change value of its element? And, how should I write so that I can change values of `x` and `y`, which can also be accessible from other files?*

Normally I'd never write in this fashion, which was forced when translating an archaic `FORTRAN77` program into `python`.

The original code heavily uses common blocks and includes, so basically I cannot trace the declarations of all variables. But still I wanted to preserve the original style of the code, so I tried to make a "global variables module", whose variables can be modified from any part of the program.

Back to my question, my guess is that `numpy.ndarray` is just pointer, and we do not change the value of a pointer, so `z` has changed. But even then the behavior of `z` seems very dangerous, that I cannot trust `z` to be shared as a global variable and its value is the same across all files. Who knows that `z` in `main` and `foo` are pointing the same memory sector?

Moreover, how can I make some variables truly *global*? Actually when I tried to translate that FORTRAN program, I tried to make class and instances of them, then pass the instance over the arguments of the function, then I realized that requires modifying the code tremendously.

What can I do?

Comment: Because you *reassigned* X and y, but you *mutated* z. This are different actions.

Comment: Note, **all** objects have exactly the same behavior in Python, what you are referring to as being "only a pointer". You should read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html. Note, Python does not support truly global variables, only module global variables. but you can import the module and modify the module namespace and this can simulate real global variables.

Comment: See: [Use of “global” keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120).

Comment: Years ago I converted a fortran program into MATLAB.  Initially all those commons were arrays in the main workspace.  Gradually I packed them into cells and structs, and eventually into the new class system.

Comment: Thanks to all the comments. I should look up juanpa suggested, but eventually it’d be better to organize them into some objects or something.

Answer (score 0):

You imported the variables and worked with your local copies.  `x` and `y` are integers, immutable types, and are therefore assigned locally.  However, when you worked with `z`, you reached into a mutable type and altered an element thereof.

If you want to change the package variables (in the original package), then you need to import the package itself and alter *those* values:

```
# foo.py
# from bar import *
import bar
def foo():
    bar.x=1
    bar.y=1
    bar.z[0]=1


# main.py
from foo import *
import bar
print(bar.x,bar.y,bar.z)
# 0 0 [0]
foo()
print(bar.x,bar.y,bar.z)
# 0 0 [1]
```

Output:

```
0 0 [0]
1 1 [1]
```